# How does one generate a random # between -10 and 10 and add this value to every object in a list's position Vector2

Tags: c#, random, for-loop

I am making a program in C# that creates a list of tree objects that have graphics that display them all in a grid like fashion. After creating them I will have it to where each individual tree is moveed a random distance between -10 and 10 over the x and y axis; this will hopefully produce a look of scattered trees. I'm still new to C# basically.

**My main problems are:**

*I'm not sure if it's possible to generate a number between -10 and 10 with my method*

```
int randX = RandomClass.Next(-10, 10);
```

*When I "skew" (skew is a loose term that I used to mean "move" in this context, its nothing literal) each tree's position, it seems as though I am applying the save amount of vertical and horizontal movement to many trees and not to one single tree individually.*

```
public void SkewTrees() 
        {
            if (skewed == false)
            {
                Vector2 emptyVector = Vector2.Zero;

                int randX = RandomClass.Next(0, 100);
                int randY = RandomClass.Next(0, 100);
                Vector2 randSkew = new Vector2(randX , randY);

                position=new Vector2(position.X+randSkew.X, position.Y+randSkew.Y);
                skewed = true;
            }
        }
```

Full Code with link to actual output:
http://pastebin.com/zZ246t7U

Answer (score 1):

For the random between -10 to 10, try something this way :

```
int rand = RandomClass.Next(1, 10) - RandomClass.Next(1, 10);
```

Or

```
 int rand = RandomClass.Next(0, 20) - 10;
```

Or

```
int rand = RandomClass.Next(-10, 10);
```

Works too.

Comment: Random class can generate negative values with Next(int, int) method

Comment: Note that sum of two random numbers has  quite different probability distribution. There is only approximately 1/100 chance to get 10 or -10 but 1/10 chance to get 0.

Comment: Oh, yes, and about : (1,10)-(1,10) ?

Comment: Why not `RandomClass.Next(0,20) - 10` - still the same range, and same distribution of numbers

Answer (score 0):

The Random-class produces a deterministic and reproducible sequence of numbers. It takes its seed from Environment.TickCount which changes every 15ms approximately. Therefore every instance of Random that you construct within such a 15ms time interval will produce exactly the same numbers.

In order to fix your code you need to ensure that you either use a good seed value or reuse a single Random class.

I recommend that you create a static variable with a single Random instance. Your entire program can reuse this variable.